# QWebEngineView with parent Widget is small

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to display a web page with a QWidget as a parent, this Widget is inside a layout which is covering the window (I dragged the vertical layout to the window and resize it then dragged the Widget) but when i run the program the page is displaying in a small widget.

This is my code:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtWebEngineWidgets>
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;

    QWidget *parent = w.findChild<QWidget*>("widget");
    QWebEngineView *view = new QWebEngineView(parent);
    view->load(QUrl("https://www.google.com/"));
    view->show();
    w.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

This is the program:[image]

this is the Qt Designer

[image]

im new using qt

Comment: Note that the code shown does *not* have any layout and doesn't make use of your generated ui file -- that's the problem. Please take a look at the [examples](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/examples-designer.html).

Comment: is the layout not created in QT Designer?

Comment: You probably want to add the QWebView to the `verticalLayout`, instead of adding it as a child  of `widget`.

Comment: My point is that you're adding `view` as a *direct* child of `w` so `view` isn't managed by any layout.

Comment: Another approach may be to use `QWebView` as a promoted widget.

Comment: Thanks, i added the view widget to the layout and worked.